# Django rest framework: how to turn off/on pagination in ModelViewSet

Tags: django, csv, pagination, django-rest-framework

I'm using [Django REST framework](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/tree/master) with [djangorestframework-csv](https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-rest-framework-csv) with default pagination settings, but when request is with format "CSV", there is no need in paginaion. Is possible to disable pagination with:

`pagination_class = None`

it's possible to change it dynamically?

```
class ObjectViewSet(BaseViewSet, viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Object.objects.none()
    serializer_class = ObjectSerializer
    pagination_class = None # if format is "CSV"
    # pagination_class = None # if fromat isn't "CSV"
```

Thanks.

Comment: just find a bug when no page_size in query_params,raise keyerror.i have update new code,please copy the new one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One option would be to dynamically disable pagination on the view by setting a `no_page` query parameter:

```
def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
    if 'no_page' in request.query_params:
        return None

    return super().paginate_queryset(queryset, request, view)
```

Comment: It doesn't work anymore (at least not in latest version), look at my answer

Answer (score 8):

### This solution is working for me

**DRF Version: 3.11.0**

**Django Version: 2.2.7**

By default pagination is working but when I will pass the query param 'no_page' then pagination will be disabled: 
like: http://localhost:8000/api/city/?no_page

```
class CityListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.CitySerializer
    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, view=None):
        if 'no_page' in self.request.query_params:
            return None
        else:
            return self.paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, self.request, view=self)
```

Answer (score 7):

if you just want to turn on or off pagination by client dynamically,you can custom Pagination class as:

```
class Pagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 100

    def get_page_size(self, request):
        if self.page_size_query_param:
            page_size = min(int(request.query_params.get(self.page_size_query_param, self.page_size)),
                        self.max_page_size)
            if page_size > 0:
                return page_size
            elif page_size == 0:
                return None
            else:
                pass
        return self.page_size
```

use this class as your pagination_class and you can turn off pagination by request url "http://www.example.com/some_object/?page_size=0", ?page_size=0 will disable pagination.
if you just want disable pagination when request format is CVS,you can try what danilke said.

Comment: this works like a charm; question: is it possible to disable pagination but keep the pagination structure? I mean, keeping the data array under the same key in the resulting JSON? thanks

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work anymore (at least not in latest version), you should do something like

```
 def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
     if 'page' not in request.query_params:
            return queryset
     return super().paginate_queryset(queryset)
```

and call the function with `self.paginate_queryset(queryset, request)` when inside the list method

Comment: Worth mentioning your DRF version as this didn't work on 3.11, seems the API changes frequently!

Answer (score 2):

simply you can use `pagination_class = None` inside your class:

```
class MyClassBasedView(ModelViewSet):
    pagination_class = None
```

Comment: you solution does not allow to enable/disable pagination dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a more future-proof approach - open up `my_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py` - replacing `my_venv` and your Python version, scroll to around line 165 and copy the method signature for `paginate_queryset`. Also check what it returns `if self.paginator is None` - that is what to return if you want to disable pagination.

On DRF 3.11 the parent method signature is `paginate_queryset(self, queryset)`, and `if self.paginator is None` it returns `None`, so I used:

```
def paginate_queryset(self, queryset):
    if 'page_id' in self.request.query_params:
        return None
    return super().paginate_queryset(queryset)
```

I haven't tested it but I guess the answer to the OP question is (assuming a fairly default DRF config):

```
if ('format' in self.request.query_params and 
        self.request.query_params['format'] == 'csv'):
```

Answer (score 1):

### My solution:

- default but customizable `page_size`
- only applies pagination if `page` param is provided
- otherwise returns the whole list

```py
# paginators.py

class CustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10  # default
    page_size_query_param = "page_size"  # param to set a custom page_size
    max_page_size = 50

    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
        # if the page param is not provided, do not apply pagination
        if request.query_params.get(self.page_query_param, None) is None:
            return None

        return super().paginate_queryset(queryset, request, view)
```

Usage:

```py
#views.py

from .paginators import CustomPagination

class ObjectViewSet(BaseViewSet, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Object.objects.none()
    serializer_class = ObjectSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPagination
```

Tested and working with Django 4.2 and DRF 3.14.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

```
class PaginatedCSVRenderer (CSVRenderer):
    results_field = 'results'

    def render(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(data, list):
            data = data.get(self.results_field, [])
        return super(PaginatedCSVRenderer, self).render(data, *args, **kwargs)
```

and than:

```
class ObjectViewSet(BaseViewSet, viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Object.objects.none()
    serializer_class = ObjectSerializer
    renderer_classes =  (JSONRenderer, PaginatedCSVRenderer)
```

and delete from settings:

```
   'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
```