# maximum page size queryset in generic views django rest

Tags: django, pagination, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

How can we achieve page_size=max for generic API view in Django rest framework? ?page_size=max work with drf-extensions but only for Viewsets not with generics  ListAPIView. Can someone confirm how can we do this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: you can use limit offset pagination where you can control page size with limit parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Use `paginate_by`, `paginate_by_param` and `max_paginate_by` in your `ListAPIView` viewset for the maximum allowed page size.

```
class PaginatedListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = ExampleModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExampleModelSerializer    
    paginate_by = 10 # Default to 10
    paginate_by_param ='page_size' # Allow client to override, using `?page_size=xxx`.
    max_paginate_by = 100 # Maximum limit allowed when using `?page_size=xxx`.
```

> Refer: [pagination-in-the-generic-views](http://djangorestframework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-guide/pagination/#pagination-in-the-generic-views)

Answer (score 0):

Use Pagination in your queryset to get objects

Refer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/pagination/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your response. but what I was exactly finding is the duplicate of below question:
[Django rest framework: how to turn off/on pagination in ModelViewSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370252/django-rest-framework-how-to-turn-off-on-pagination-in-modelviewset)

We just have to override get_page_size() method from Django rest framework PageNumberPagination class.